# Simple router/multiplexer, request path is empty for the static file request

Tags: go

I'm running a server only at the `/` endpoint and it's handler parses the request URL path to determine what to do. It handles the home `/` path and a default case for any other path. Other than that, I want to serve a static CSS file but the path never matches "css/style.css".

My templates have other href links like `/help` or `/user` that work just fine. If I add print statements to print the `path`, I see the correct output. But in my `index.html` template where I want to link to my css, the path is always the `/` path.

I can see the network activity in my browser but not sure how to fix it. I see a request from `localhost:8080/css/style.css` but from the response code, it gets handled by my default case. I see another request from ```localhost:8080/```` that returns a stylesheet with the initiator being style.css oddly enough. I don't understand this activity.

```
http.HandleFunc("/", svr.Handler)
```

```
func (s *Server) Handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    path := strings.TrimPrefix(r.URL.Path, "/")

    switch path {
    case "", "/":
        //handle homepage, process data
        err := s.template.ExecuteTemplate(w, "index.html", data)
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
        }
    case "css/style.css":
        //serve CSS file
        http.ServeFile(w, r, "../templates/css/style.css")
    default:
        //handle other, process data
        err := s.template.ExecuteTemplate(w, "index.html", data)
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
        }
    }
}
```

In my `index.html` template:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
```

Comment: Suggestion: don't use a switch inside a single handler. Instead, create several separate handlers. A [http.FileServer](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#FileServer) could handle files for urls starting with "/css/", for example.

Comment: @Mark I'll try that. I think the issue is that I'm trying to handle the dynamic route ```/{anything}``` where the path could be anything including ```css/style.css```.